# Online website builder

Tags: open-source, web-development

I'm going to develop an **online website builder**, aimed at general public (just like wix.com etc). Where people will Log in and create their website without having to do any coding stuff. They will create web pages and content by using drag & drop widgets and components. Once they complete their website, they will have option to publish it online on our servers or they can download the HTML files and host them on their own server.

I need to know if there is an existing open source solution? Preferably written in PHP, but I'm open to other suggestions as well.

I searched but found results like WordPress, Drupal etc., which is of course not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Why exactly are CMS like WordPress and Drupal not what you’re looking? They *might* offer plugins/modules for your use case.

Comment: You are looking to clone http://www.silex.me/ ?

Comment: @unor : Thank you for the response, I had never thought that WordPress or Drupal can be used for these purposes. I'll look into them with that perspective now. Meanwhile if you can point me to any resource regarding my use case, then please do tell me :)

Comment: @mawg Thank you for the response, Yep I came across Silex and found that it is pretty much what I'm going to build. But **Silex** is built with Python and I'm going to opt for `PHP` or `C#`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a nice open source website builder script.

[Git Hub Link](https://github.com/Vegetam/BootstrapPageGenerator)

I'm posting this, in case any one else need to have this problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

I found a service called [Ghost](http://ghost.org)

It is described in more detail and confirmed to be open source in this blog post by the developer: http://john.onolan.org/project-ghost/

This software is described as being purpose built for making blogs, and only blogs, as a "WordPress-lite" type of solution. In fact the developer states in his blog post that it is a fork of WordPress and as such has cross compatibility for themes and plugins, which may be a desirable feature for your project/use-case. it has both an online component like you describe, and a downloadable version to be installed on web servers.

Here is its GitHub page: https://github.com/tryghost/Ghost

Comment: Hey Tim thank you very much :) I'll give it a  go and let you know